# Is it possible to add multiple CAs to kafka truststore

Tags: apache-kafka, ca

While configuring kafka security using ssl certificates, is it possible to have multiple certification authorities in kafka truststore .jks file ?

When i tried adding multiple CAs to truststore, only one CA can be added with the alias caroot. Looks like kafka supports only one CA at a time. if we can add multiple CAs please provide the steps

Comment: Full disclosure, I have not tested this, but my expectation would be that Kafka ignores the alias and simply checks all certificates in the truststore whether it matches the opposing side. So you should be fine with just importing additional CAs with different aliases.
A quick search through the source code shows no matches for "cacert" which would support this. Just try it I guess :-)